# Auction website with Paxos consensus algorithm

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, consensus

As a project, I'm trying to construct a P2P auction web application with paxos in a high latency environment. The idea is that each user visiting the website will keep a small log file with the interested item and current price/bid. Each submitted bid will use a client-sided paxos algorithm to contact nodes all nodes to reach a consensus of the bid value. The idea is quite simple, user wishing to buy/sell an item, either add a new entry to the log or update an existing one. However, since its an auction, time is an issue, especially with high-lantecy.

I have a couple of problems with this idea, which I hope it is achievable. How would the final bid be finalized? E.g. how would ALL the user know that bid has ended and this user is the winner? Client-side validation can be circumvented with JavaScript and timestamping can be forged. What other options do I have?